# Erro em passar valor para View no codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Em uma aplicação simples. Um valor é passado para view. Porém o codeigniter informa um erro:

**Código PHP:**

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

            parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $this->load->model('user_model');
                $this->load->library('session');
    }


    public function index()
    {

    }


    public function alterarUsuario(){

      $teste ="2";
      $this->load->view('teste.php', $teste);

    }
}

?>
```

**Código View:**

```
<?php

    $teste = $_REQUEST['teste'];
    echo "Resposta: ".$id;

?>
```

**Mensagem Erro:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É comum passar mais de um valor para a view, nesse caso você deve registrar o nome que a variável será acessivel na view o respectivo valor, isso é feito atraves de um array ou objeto. Que é passado como segundo argumento para o método `view()`.

```
public function alterarUsuario(){
    $params['id'] = 2;
    $params['teste'] = 'algum valor';
    $this->load->view('teste.php', $params);
}
```

Na view chame as variáveis pelo indice definido no controller:

```
<?php echo "id: ". $id ." valor: ". $teste; ?>
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[CI Documentação - View](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

Comment: só complementando, a documentação em portugues pode ajudar, https://cibr.github.io/User-Guide-CodeIgniter-PtBr/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view